# TSQL UPDATE based on MAX (Date) in other table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I was hoping someone can give me a hand with my problem. I have 2 tables: Supplier and Payment.

Supplier table consists of the supplier number and a flag indicating whether the account is enabled or not.

```
Supplier
--------
NUM
ENAFLG
```

Then I have a payment table that shows all the payments that suppliers made, including the date of the payment (ACCDAT).

```
Payment
-------
SUPNUM
ACCDAT
```

What I need to do is to make the supplier disabled if their last payment had been made before '01/01/2016'. Here is what i have but I get the following error:

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

I do need to be able to pass multiple values to update the Supplier table.

```
UPDATE dbo.SUPPLIER 
SET ENAFLG_0 = 1
WHERE NUM_0 = (SELECT pay.SUPNUM_0
               FROM dbo.PAYMENT AS pay
               JOIN dbo.SUPPLIER AS bps ON bps.NUM_0 = pay.SUPNUM_0
               GROUP BY pay.SUPNUM_0
               HAVING MAX(pay.ACCDAT_0) < '01/01/2016')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `NUM_0` is a foreign key to `SUPNUM_0` yes? Should be able to do a JOIN then instead of a subquery.

Comment: Try changing `=` to `IN`, or convert to a `JOIN`, or use `WHERE EXISTS` instead of `WHERE NUM_0`.  Any should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE dbo.SUPPLIER 
SET ENAFLG_0 = 1
WHERE NUM_0 in (select  pay.SUPNUM_0
                    from dbo.PAYMENT as pay
                    JOIN dbo.SUPPLIER as bps
                    on bps.NUM_0 =  pay.SUPNUM_0
                    GROUP BY pay.SUPNUM_0
                    Having MAX(pay.ACCDAT_0) < '01/01/2016'
                    )
```

Comment: Can't believe i missed that. Thank you!